# costmap2D from 3Dpointcloud

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d-ros, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup. After setting various prerequisites for launch, with move_base launch file, move_base node results in 2D costmap, obstacles, inflated obstacles etc. In rviz visualization, it is observed that obstacles detected are not getting cleared in subsequent published costmaps. Old obstacles becomes part of current costmap as well. Suddenly after sometime, everything is cleared and a correct cost map is displayed.
Am I missing setting up any specific parameter? Current all parameters are as advised in tutorial.
I had set "observation_persistence: 0.0" in costmap_common_params.yaml but it do not help.

Following is a set of screenshots of rviz

Screen 1:

Screeshot 2:

Screeshot 3:

Screeshot 4:

Screenshot5:

This is taken after around 12 seconds from screenshot4. Semicircles in front and back of robot are artifacts of costmap. It is plain road.

This is published on topic /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27608/costmap2d-from-3dpointcloud/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-14**:
This is when driving by an obstacle?

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-14**:
We had captured one data set as bag which I am replaying for test purposes. The accumulations of previous obstacles in latest costmap is happening continuously. For example when taking a turn in. In this case, obstacles which were on left will shift in horizon and also previous position will stay.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-14**:
I had edited original question to add screenshots to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tuning suggestions in that tutorial are designed for indoor robots.  Once you take it outdoors you will need to make the costmap much more permissive for not flat roads and miscalibrations in your data.

FYI: Having worked on autonomous vehicles roads are *not* flat at all.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd similar problems visualizing point clouds in a specific computer. The problem was the same as your, the point cloud was not cleared from rviz event if there were no data, at the end the problem was the graphic card of that computer, because I checked the algorithm on other machines and it worked perfecly. It seems stupid, but have you tried on other PCs?

---

Originally posted by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) with karma: 74 on 2012-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-21**:
We had tried on different machines, although not thinking about this possibility. I believe obstacles are not getting cleared properly. Also My frame moves with the robot. I want it this way. This is input to local planner.

**Comment by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) on 2012-02-21**:
I suppose that you're well defining the observation sources (at costmap_common_params.yaml), with the clearing parameter set to "true", right? (it's something obious but we must be sure...;P)

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-22**:
Yes, it is set to true. Screenshot 5 even confirms this. After playing data for around 15secs, costmap gets cleared.

**Comment by [Àngel - IRI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1795/%C3%A0ngel---iri/) on 2012-02-22**:
And also and obvious parameter that it must be checked, the Decay Time in rviz, is set to 0, right?

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-02-22**:
Yes it is.